# Drop Duplicates isn't working on python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working in python, and have a dataframe(df), which includes the column 'CONTRACT_ID'. There are different numbers in this column. There is also another column called NPV, which is made up of numbers.

```
 CONTRACT_ID                       NPV          
0     1                            90                

1     1                            90                   

2     2                            130                     

3     2                            130   

4     3                            105

5     3                            105
...

...
```

I don't want these duplicates to appear twice, so I tried to drop duplicates (only on column CONTRACT_ID) using this code:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['CONTRACT_ID'], keep=False)
```

My expected result would be like so:

```
    CONTRACT_ID                    NPV                       
0     1                            90                  

1     2                            130                   

2     3                            105                 
    ...
```

The code didn't work however. It ran with no error, but it simply didn't get rid of the duplicates at all. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you reassign to the DataFrame?

Comment: `df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['CONTRACT_ID'], keep=False)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forget reasign `DataFrame`:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['CONTRACT_ID'], keep=False)
```

Comment: oof that's embarrassing. Congrats on grabbing an easy best answer